# Perform operation on DataFrame and get result as Dataframe which matches either of the condition present in another DataFrame in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame df1:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[31,12,32,65],[42,19,22,78],[76,13,45,68],[43,37,43,71],[43,18,34,73]],columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

and another DataFrame df2:

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame([["B",">20"],["C",">40"],["D","<70"],["A","<40"]],columns = ["Feature","Condition"])
```

Want to perform operation on df1 using respective conditions present in df2. The result should be a DataFrame which meets either of the condition present in df2 as shown below Output.

```
Output = pd.DataFrame([[31,12,32,65],[76,13,45,68],[43,37,43,71]],columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
```

How to do it? Please help.

Comment: you already asked this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63597196/perform-operation-on-column-of-data-frame-based-on-condition-given-to-column-in/63597785#63597785

Comment: That was for a single column, not entire data frame which matches either of the condition

Comment: well you are a tech gut right - use your own capability

Comment: I am a beginner in programming, I tried but was not able to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`agg`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.agg.html) to create condition then [`query`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
# create condition 
conds = " or ".join(df2.agg(" ".join, axis=1).tolist())

# apply condition
df = df1.query(conds)

print(df)

    A   B   C   D
0  31  12  32  65
2  76  13  45  68
3  43  37  43  71
```